# VS Code Error: Error while fetching extensions: XHR Failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, windows-7

I am using ***Windows 7 32-bit*** and I use **VS Code version 1.70.3** [The last operational version for Windows 7]. Everything was working fine, I had a bunch of extensions but one day, this error popped up and till now it has not been fixed. Now, whenever I search for any extensions, nothing loads up except a line `Error while fetching extension: XHR Failed`. I went online but couldn't find anything that worked. I saw a few posts on Stack but there was nothing useful that worked so I thought to post it once again. I know I can get around it by downloading the extensions online at but you know, that is too annoying and time-consuming. (especially, if you just have ten extensions for color themes)

Following are the things I tried:

1. I tried to reinstall VS Code three times.
2. I also installed a different version but it too shows the same error. (v 1.70.3)
3. The internet told me something about going to settings.json and deleting some lines related to `proxy-settings` and `proxy-authorization`. I did them all but nothing worked. (See Below)
4. I tried disabling the firewall and running VS Code as Administrator.

Once again, I have **Windows 7 with 32-bit** and **VS Code version 1.70.3**

My Proxy Settings (if it helps) :

[My VSCode Proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uioaf.png)

Also, my `proxy-Authorization` is set to null and `proxy-Support` to on
I tried tweaking the settings of each one of them but nothing worked. Maybe, I did something wrong...

*P.S.- I don't really know much about proxies so if there is a workaround or maybe you can give such an answer that would also help me understand them, that would be much appreciated else I could also work around anything else, that too would be equally appreciated.*

Comment: show exactly what you tried with the proxy settings.